# gfortran -fc-prototypes option for function pointers

Tags: c, fortran, function-pointers, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

The gfortran compiler has the [interoperability option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-Options.html#Interoperability-Options) -fc-prototypes which generates the correct C-prototypes for interoperable functions (which have the BIND(C) attribute).

In the link it is written: "For function pointers, a pointer to a function returning int without an explicit argument list is generated. "

I tried it with some code that contains a BIND(C) subroutine that takes a function pointer to a subroutine with 2 integer arguments. Take the Fortran code in file `test.F95`:

```
subroutine test(pf) bind(c)

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(c_funptr), intent(in), value :: pf
    
    abstract interface
        subroutine fproto(x, y) bind(c)
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
            integer(c_int), intent(in), value :: x, y
        end subroutine fproto
    end interface
    procedure(fproto), pointer :: f

    call c_f_procpointer(pf, f)
    call f(1, 2)
end subroutine test
```

Compile with: `gfortran test.F95 -c -Wall -fc-prototypes > proto.h`

This generates the C header file `proto.h` with the content:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
#define __GFORTRAN_FLOAT_COMPLEX std::complex<float>
#define __GFORTRAN_DOUBLE_COMPLEX std::complex<double>
#define __GFORTRAN_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX std::complex<long double>
extern "C" {
#else
#define __GFORTRAN_FLOAT_COMPLEX float _Complex
#define __GFORTRAN_DOUBLE_COMPLEX double _Complex
#define __GFORTRAN_LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX long double _Complex
#endif

void f ();
void fproto (int x, int y);
void test (int (*pf)());

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

As you can see, the prototype of the subroutine `fproto` in the abstract interface is correct. But the correct C prototype of the argument of the `test` subroutine, i.e. of the function pointer should be:

```
void (*pf)(int, int)
```

But gfortran generates

```
int (*pf)()
```

This does not match at all. What is the point of this? Does that mean I should always pass function pointers to functions that return int? Or is this just (intentionally?) generated wrong?

Comment: Need to see some actual code.

Comment: @evets I added some code.

Comment: The dummy argument `pf` is of type `c_funptr`: why do you expect gfortran to generate `void (*pf)(int, int)`?

Comment: @francescalus Because on the C side I have to pass a pointer to a function of type `void (*)(int, int)` and not of type `int(*)()` to the `test` function. What is the point of generating a wrong C interface? Or is the Fortran code incorrect and I should use something different than `c_funptr`? However it compiles without any warnings.

Comment: How does gfortran know when generating the C prototypes know that you expect to pass a function pointer like `void (*pf)(int, int)` rather than `int(*)()`, or any other?

Comment: @francescalus Because I assign it to the procedure pointer `f` of type `fproto` which has this definition in the abstract interface. Similarly, why does it generate `void f();` and not `void f(int, int);` when `f` is of type `fproto`?

Comment: What if you didn't have that `c_f_procptr` call, or it was used twice with different prototypes (conditionally, possibly), or it was an implicit interface?  That is, gfortran can't cover all cases so it has to choose something.  (You now have an answer covering this, so best to continue any further discussion there.)

Comment: @francescalus Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gfortran is working as designed and documented (with the relevant piece of documentation actually quoted in the question in paragraph two!) here.

The subroutine test takes a generic C function pointer as an argument.  From the perspective of interoperability of that subroutine's interface, any function can be passed in.  gfortran's interpretation of a matching function for any function is "a pointer to a function returning int without an explicit argument list".

The association of a Fortran procedure pointer with the function pointer is an execution time activity.  The prototype describes the characteristics of the function, which is a compile time concept.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I always have to correct that by hand before using it. But what about the procedure pointer `f`? Shouldn't gfortran know at compile time that this is of type `fproto` and so generate the correct C function prototype which would be `void f(int, int)`? Why `void f()`?

Comment: I don't know.  I suspect the compiler is simply getting confused for that one.